# How to list adjectives in Chinese

Tags: grammar

I am preparing for HSK 6, and its Reading Part 1, which asks you to identify a 语病 in a sentence, is notoriously hard. Here is one of the sentences from HSK 6 Reading Part 1.

周围的人都很羡慕她，说他的妻子很实惠，又能干又体贴。

My HSK 6 testbook, which comes without an explanation for each question, says that there is a 语病 in this sentence.

I am guessing that “他的妻子很实惠，又能干又体贴” should be edited to "他的妻子很实惠，能干，体贴." Am I wrong in this?

Comment: Please  re check you quote from the test paper. I feel like there s 错别字 rather than 语病. Would the original text be 周围的人都很羡慕他，说他的妻子很贤惠，又能干又体贴。

Answer (score 3):

I recognize at two 语病 in this sentence.

First, it should be

> 周围的人都很羡慕他

People envy him, not her, his wife.

Second, one should not describe a person with 实惠，实惠 describes a product, which means the product is worth the price. To describe a person, one use 贤惠，and it is usually for a woman, which generally refers to a woman who is diligent, good tempered and etc.

Answer (score 1):

The quote can be fixed as (see zzy's answer):

> 周围的人都很羡慕他，说他的妻子很贤惠，又能干又体贴。

Now, about the fix you proposed. In this sentence, 贤惠、能干、体贴 are not just a list of adjective. 能干 and 体贴 is here to explain (some of) the reasons why his wife can be described as "贤惠". There is no problem in the sentence structure here, and your proposed fix is wrong.